# DefaultAppPool suffered a fatal communication error with WWW Publishing service

Tags: asp.net, iis, windows-server-2003

Recently changes were made on the .net version on the server, post which all IIS applications are failing with the following exception.

A process serving the DefaultAppPool suffered a fatal communication error with the WWW publishing service.

Data field error no : 8007006d

Using Debug Diag tool i have generated the dump file and the analysis is as below.

- > In w3wp__DefaultAppPool__PID__3932__Date__08_06_2019__Time_01_42_15PM__731__Second_Chance_Exception_C0000005.dmp
  >   the assembly instruction at aspnet_isapi!AttachHandleToThreadPool+10
  >   in \?\C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v1.1.4322\aspnet_isapi.dll
  >   from Microsoft Corporation has caused an access violation exception
  >   (0xC0000005) when trying to read from memory location 0x00000000 on
  >   thread 9

Thread 9 - System ID 1480
Entry point   w3tp+1d70 
Create time   06/08/2019 13:41:53 
Time spent in user mode   0 Days 0:0:0.0 
Time spent in kernel mode   0 Days 0:0:0.0

Full Call Stack

```
Function     Arg 1     Arg 2     Arg 3     Arg 4   Source 
aspnet_isapi!AttachHandleToThreadPool+10     01b61e90     01b621fa     00000238     77e63d9a    
aspnet_isapi!CloseVersionedPerfData+1714     00000000     79e79ff5     00000000     79e7660d    
aspnet_isapi!CloseVersionedPerfData+1607     0000021c     01211fec     00000000     0109556c    
w3isapi!ProcessIsapiRequest+532     000c5030     0108fe20     0000021c     01211fec    
w3isapi!ProcessIsapiRequest+39     01095af8     0109556c     0108fe50     01095518    
w3core+690f     00000000     00000000     010948c8     01095480    
w3core+67f0     0108fee8     010948c8     00000000     00000001    
w3core+6774     010948c8     00000000     0108fec4     5a3966be    
w3core+6704     010948d0     010948c8     00000001     010948c8    
w3core+66be     00000001     0108fee8     002aaff8     010948c8    
w3core+6658     00000000     00000000     00000000     01093e00    
w3core+2274     00000000     00000000     00000000     00000001    
w3core+65fa     01093e00     01093e00     5a361680     002a4710    
w3dt!UlAtqAllocateMemory+16f     00000470     00000000     01093e04     0108ff8c    
w3dt!UlAtqAllocateMemory+19a     00000000     00000470     01093e04     002a4718    
w3tp!THREAD_POOL::PostCompletion+c9     00000000     002a8ab0     5a300000     0108ffb8    
w3tp!THREAD_POOL::~THREAD_POOL+153     002a4710     00000000     00000000     002a8ab0    
w3tp+1da9     002a8ab0     00000000     00000000     002a8ab0    
kernel32!GetModuleHandleA+df     5a301d70     002a8ab0     00000000     000000c8
```

Exception Information
ASPNET_ISAPI!ATTACHHANDLETOTHREADPOOL+10WARNING - DebugDiag was not able to locate debug symbols for `aspnet_isapi.dll`, so the information below may be incomplete.

- > In w3wp__DefaultAppPool__PID__3932__Date__08_06_2019__Time_01_42_15PM__731__Second_Chance_Exception_C0000005.dmp
  >   the assembly instruction at aspnet_isapi!AttachHandleToThreadPool+10
  >   in \?\C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v1.1.4322\aspnet_isapi.dll
  >   from Microsoft Corporation has caused an access violation exception
  >   (0xC0000005) when trying to read from memory location 0x00000000 on
  >   thread 9
- > Module Information  Image Name: \?\C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v1.1.4322\aspnet_isapi.dll
  >   Symbol Type:  Export  Base address: 0x00905a4d                             Time Stamp: 
  >   Thu Feb 19 20:10:03 2015   Checksum: 0x00000000                                   Comments: 
  >   Microsoft .NET Framework build environement is Retail. SafeSync
  >   counter=0  COM DLL: False Company Name:  Microsoft Corporation 
  >   ISAPIExtension: True                                   File Description:  aspnet_isapi.lib 
  >   ISAPIFilter: False                                    File Version:  1.1.4322.2515  Managed
  >   DLL: False                                    Internal Name:  aspnet_isapi.lib  VB DLL: False
  >                                    Loaded Image Name:  aspnet_isapi.dll                             Mapped Image Name:                                     Original filename:  aspnet_isapi.lib  Module name:
  >   aspnet_isapi                              Private Build:    Single Threaded:  False 
  >                             Product Name:  Microsoft (R) .NET Framework  Module Size:  264.00 KBytes                             Product Version:  1.1.4322.2515  Symbol File Name:  aspnet_isapi.dll                          Special Build:  &

Comment: I don't have a certain answer, but have you tried re-registering the dot net version with iis via: 'ASPNET_REGIIS'? In the past, re-running this has resolved some random issues for me.

Comment: Which version of IIS?

Comment: IIS 6.0, yes I have registered the dot net version using aspnet_regiis -i command.

Comment: Eek. Sort of clutching, here, but could try creating a new, empty dot net application / site in IIS. Maybe nothing but a web.config and an aspx file and see if it will run. It looks at first glance like a fundamental IIS issue, and not something with your application versus the version of dot net, but would be good to eliminate that. If that's the case, then even an empty dot net site should fail..

Answer (score 0):

To fix errors related to.DLL file you need to download aspnet_isapi.dll and copy it to the installation folder of the application, or copy it into the Windows system folder and it should fix the error.

You could also follow the below steps to Reset ASP.NET settings:

1) register dll file by running below command(run command prompt as administrator)

```
regsvr32 "C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v1.1.4322\aspnet_isapi.dll"
```

2)Run the following command line to view the NS Web applications associated with .NET 1.1.4322:

```
 C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v1.1.4322\aspnet_regiis.exe -lk
```

3)Run the following command line to remove all associations to .NET 1.1.4322:

```
 C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v1.1.4322\aspnet_regiis.exe -k W3SVC/
```

4)Run the following command line to add the NS Web applications back to .NET 1.1.4322:

```
 C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v1.1.4322\aspnet_regiis.exe -i
```

5)reset the iis:

```
 iisreset
```

after doing these things check the below things:

open iis manager. select the default site and right-click and select Properties. Click on the ASP.NET tab and, in the "ASP.NET version," select the 1.1.4322 version from the drop list. Click OK. 
In the IIS Manager, go to Web Server Extensions and make sure that at least ASP.NET v1.1.4322 is allowed. If allowed, then it should not be a problem.

Comment: Hi Jalpa, I have followed all the steps starting from 1, but still the same exception appears when the application is accessed. As soon as a web request hits, the same error is occurring. Does this have to do with identity service accounts used on the machine? maybe access related issue?

Comment: which permission assigned to C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v1.1.4322\aspnet_regiis.exe file?you could try to check the event viewer for more deail.

Comment: do you have any other. net version installed on your machine?

Comment: No, this is the only .net version installed v1.1.4322. From the event viewer we are getting "A process serving the DefaultAppPool suffered a fatal communication error with the WWW publishing service." Data field error no : 8007006d